# Write to String using the FixedLengthClassBuilder

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I have a c# class called "SepaRecord", already defined in a dll which I cannot modify.
I have a List at runtime which I need to convert into a fixed length file.

The approach which I have tried is, using the FixedLengthClassBuilder I create a runtime definition of the record, as below:

```
FixedLengthClassBuilder fileRecordBuilder = new FixedLengthClassBuilder("SepaRecord");
fileRecordBuilder.AddField("RecordCode", 2, typeof(string));
fileRecordBuilder.AddField("CurrencyCode", 3, typeof(string));
fileRecordBuilder.AddField("CreditAmount", 15, typeof(int));
// other fields follow....
```

RecordCode, CurrencyCode, CreditAmount, etc are fields defined the "SepaRecord" class in the DLL.

I would expect that if I pass the list to the FileHelperEngine, I would get back a delimited string:

```
List<SepaRecord> lst = this.goGetMyList();
string ret = this.FileHelperEngine.WriteString(lst);
```

But of course it did not work since the FixedLengthClassBuilder builts and compiles a type/class at runtime and compares it with the class/type of the argument.

Question is: Is there a better approach to do what I am trying to do?
And a suggestion: Why bother with type checks?  Just compare on the field level.  I think this would make the runtime engine more flexible.

Appreciate any help
Chris

Answer (score 0):

FileHelpers does not provide auto-mapping of fields from other classes. That functionality is handled better by other libraries like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

FileHelpers is a library for describing text files. The `FixedLengthClassBuiler` is creating a specification of the text output.

You need to map the contents of your `List<SepaRecord>` to an `IEnumerable<T>` where T is the type created by `

```
Type recordClass = fileRecordBuilder.CreateRecordClass();
var recordClassLst = lst.Select(sepaRecord => ConvertToRecordClass(sepaRecord));    
string ret = this.FileHelperEngine.WriteString(recordClassLst);
```

You'd need to code the `ConvertToRecordClass` function yourself, via AutoMapper if you like.

*Additional note:* Rather than using the `FixedLengthClassBuilder` you will probably find it easier to create a concrete class for your text file spec like this:

```
[FixedLengthRecord(",")]
public class MyClass
{
    [FixedLengthRecord(2)]
    public string RecordCode;
    [FixedLengthRecord(3)]
    public string CurrencyCode;
    [FixedLengthRecord(15)]
    public int CreditAmount;
    // etc.
}
```

Then it is easier to create an `IEnumerable<MyClass>`. (The `FixedLengthClassBuiler` is more useful when your class record definition is not known until run time).